# What is an easy way to do a sorted diff between two files?

Tags: unix, shell

I have two files in which some of the lines have changed order. I would like to be able to compare these.

One website suggested something that looks like this:

```
diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)
```

But this yields the error: *Missing name for redirect.*

I am using tcsh. Is the command above for a different shell?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Some shell ( zsh for sure, bash may be ) do this magic allowing the output of a command to appear as a filename to another command using /dev/fd<num>  device.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: See my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23303/diff-where-lines-are-mostly-the-same-but-out-of-order

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This redirection syntax is bash specific. Thus it won't work in tcsh.

You can call bash and specify the command directly:

```
bash -c 'diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)'
```

Comment: This is a great tip, but I don't fully understand why it works.  Could you explain how wrapping it with "bash -c" makes the redirection work?

Comment: Wrapping with `bash -c` is necessary if your present shell isn't `bash`.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a function for it:

```
function diffs() {
        diff "${@:3}" <(sort "$1") <(sort "$2")
}
```

Call it like this:

```
diffs file1 file2 [other diff args, e.g. -y]
```

Presumably you could alter it as per David Schmitt's answer if necessary.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there a better way?

Yes, there is.

Use `comm` utility:

> usage: comm [-123i] file1 file2

Comment: From the man page: _The comm utility assumes that the files are lexically sorted; all characters participate in line comparisons._

Comment: Doesn't it allow sorting only in one, predefined way? 
The method with redirecting the sort command is a way more flexible with this respect. If it works, of course.

Answer (score 8):

If this does not work for your shell, just do it in 3 lines:

```
sort text1 > text1.sorted
sort text2 > text2.sorted
diff text1.sorted text2.sorted
```

Simple but should work...

Answer (score 5):

In `fish` shell,

```
diff (sort a.txt | psub) (sort b.txt | psub)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your posted 'diff' is that `diff` can only receive *one* file via `stdin`. So I think you'll have to write at least one sorted file to a temporary file.

```
diff - file.txt
```

will diff stdin versus a file.txt. The '-' represents stdin

EDIT: I'd assumed that the process substitution would work via stdin. But that's not the case and the above is going via `/dev/fd/{num}` as pointed out by VardhanDotNet above.