# Convert /bin/bash command to /bin/sh command

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, sh, process-substitution

I have the following command...

```
/bin/bash -c 'diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)'
```

It sorts each file and pipes them into the diff function. This works well if `/bin/bash` exists. However, the system I'm on only has `/bin/sh`. I'm struggling to find the equivalent command for this.

If I run...

```
/bin/sh -c 'diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)'
```

I will get...

> /bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected "("

Comment: Aaaalmost a duplicate: [What is an easy way to do a sorted diff between two files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714421/3266847) – answers do cover how to avoid process substitution.

Comment: @Jetchisel sort of. It puts me in the right direction, but the answer below is the one I went with.

Comment: That's the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714444/3266847) in the suggested duplicate target.

Comment: @BenjaminW yes you're right. I'm just seeing that now. I was thinking someone could give me an answer without creating temp files but since it doesn't seem possible then you are right

Comment: Even the bash version creates temp files. It just doesn't involve you in the creation and cleanup. ;)

Comment: @PaulHodges the Bash version also creates tomporary FIFO. Check this with `bash -c 'echo <(sort file1) <(sort file2)'` → `/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62`. With POSIX shell, you have to handle the creation for the FIFO devices. You would be able to use numerical file descriptors as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The POSIX shell equivalent of Bash:

```sh
bash -c 'diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)'
```

is:

```sh
sh -c 'trap "rm -fr -- \"$t\"" EXIT ABRT INT;t=$(mktemp -d);mkfifo "$t/a" "$t/b";sort text1>"$t/a"&sort text2>"$t/b"&diff "$t/b" "$t/a"'
```

Or in a civilized way

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

trap 'rm -fr -- "$tmpdir"' EXIT ABRT INT
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

FIFO_A="$tmpdir/fifoA"
FIFO_B="$tmpdir/fifoB"
mkfifo -- "$FIFO_A" "$FIFO_B"
sort text1 > "$FIFO_A" &
sort text2 > "$FIFO_B" &
diff -- "$FIFO_B" "$FIFO_A"
```

Comment: Does that need a `wait`?

Comment: @PaulHodges I forgot the `mkfifo` in the oneliner. Fixed now.

Comment: This is amazing, took me a while to understand most of it. I'm still confused by the `trap` command. Could you briefly explain what that part is doing?

Comment: on shell error or shell exit, deletes the temporary file, correct?

Comment: @buydadip It deletes the temporary directory and its contained named FIFO devices on shell exit, shell break or shell abort (`Control` + `c`). An error will not trigger this trap unless it registers to the ERR trap.

Comment: so if the diff cmd were to fail for whatever reason, then the tmpdir will remain?

Comment: @buydadip If any of the cmd fails, at one point the script reaches an EXIT and do triggers the EXIT trap that removes the tempdir.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just simple temp files?

```
sort text1 >a; sort text2 >b; diff b a; rm a b;
```

Comment: Or you could: `sort text1 > a; sort text2 | diff - a ; rm a`

Comment: and `mktemp` might be warranted.

Comment: Agreed - I much prefer a more fleshed-out version with `mktemp` and error checking, etc.

Comment: if the command fails on the `diff`, the temp files will remain right? that could be an issue for me

Comment: No, these statements are not conditional. Each is executed regardless of the success or failure of the others. I prefer more self-aware code, but this was a simplistic approach.