# What is the most effective way to compare two files line by line (lines are not ordered)?

Tags: java, file, comparison

I have two files of more or less 20 thousand lines and I need to compare them the problem is that the lines are not in the same order, each line is unique because they are records of a DB but the line of file one can be line 15.000 in the second file, I tried to go through one line of the first file and look for that line in the second using a BufferReader but for each line takes about 10 seconds 17.000 times would be a long time, is there a more effective way to do this?
.

Comment: *because they are records of a DB* - retrieve the data already sorted.  Then fail fast.

Comment: What is the intended result of "comparing" them?  Are you just trying to determine which lines are/are not in both?  Load the first file line-wise into a HashSet and then look up each line from the second file in turn.

Comment: What is the result of comparison? Do you only want to know if the sets of lines are identical or find the lines missing in the other file? Can the files contain duplicate lines and how do you expect them to be handled?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [`bash -c 'diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714421/what-is-an-easy-way-to-do-a-sorted-diff-between-two-files)

Comment: @undefined symbol
 Yes, the data goes throough several DBs so file 1 is the data in one of the DBs and file two is the data in another DB  so i need to validade if the data is tha same, every line is a record, but I can not use a HashSet becasue I can not load all the data in memory due is to much data so it will end in  a memori error.

Comment: sounds like sql is the proper tool to use.

Comment: @Bohemian I would def suggest using -w flag to ignore whitespace characters. I had no idea why tf two files werent matching and I compared line by line to realise its all the same, then checked the special characters. `comm` is also pretty good.

Comment: How big are the records?  If they're 1K chars each then 20,000 records is ~40 MB plus overhead, not a particularly huge size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash function

1. Generate a hash value for each line in the first file. You can use a hash function like MD5 or SHA-1
2. Store the hash values in a hash table or a dictionary data structure, with the hash value as the key and the line number as the value.
3. Iterate through each line in the second file, generate a hash value for each line, and check for matches against your file1 dictionary

code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FileComparator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file1 = new File("file1.txt");
        File file2 = new File("file2.txt");

        HashMap<String, String> file1Hashes = getFileHashes(file1);
        HashMap<String, String> file2Hashes = getFileHashes(file2);

        for (String key : file1Hashes.keySet()) {
            if (!file2Hashes.containsKey(key)) {
                System.out.println(key + " not found in file2");
            } else if (!file1Hashes.get(key).equals(file2Hashes.get(key))) {
                System.out.println(key + " differs in file1 and file2");
            }
        }

        for (String key : file2Hashes.keySet()) {
            if (!file1Hashes.containsKey(key)) {
                System.out.println(key + " not found in file1");
            }
        }
    }

    private static HashMap<String, String> getFileHashes(File file) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> hashes = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            hashes.put(line, getHash(line));
        }

        reader.close();
        return hashes;
    }

    private static String getHash(String line) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hashBytes = md.digest(line.getBytes());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte b : hashBytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for you?

Comment: This will not end in memory problems ? I mean store 17,000 items in a Map is that okay?

Comment: I mean, most computers these days have at least a few GB memory ..

Comment: meaning yea it should easily fit in memory, check the size of your files ..

Comment: If fileA has three lines that are identical and in fileB this line is repeated 4 times, then your code will not report that the files are different.

Comment: @AndresAcosta You can store only the hash value of the row instead of the entire row content！`Map<Integer, String> file1`,`file1.put(1, "line1 hash value")`, `file1.put(2, "line2 hash value")`. `Map<Integer, String> file2`,`file2.put(1, "line1 hash value")`, `file2.put(2, "line2 hash value")`.

Comment: the code shown doesn't include the filecount, but you can store it in the hash map if you want to

Comment: Or it is better to use the hash value of the row as the key, traverse the first map, and then use the key of the first map to get from the second map

Comment: @impossible-sudoku I took your aproach but I am using the String.hashCode() value as key for every line and it is working fine, thank you so much.

Comment: @AndresAcosta great, just be sure you are using a hash function that is wide enough, the chance of getting an accidental collision for 20,000 random values using the built in hash function is over 10%

Comment: if the answer was useful please mark it as accepted to show that it solved your problem, and is also beneficial to me